# Render error when parsing configmap in helm package

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm package whose values.yaml contains something like:

```
ere:
  adm-users:
  - userName: test1
    password: test2
  - useName: user3
    password: user4
```

and I want to include these values in an xml file dynamically for which in the deployment.yaml i've included a configmap. My configmap contains something like:

```
data:
  PoolServer.xml: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "files/config/PoolServer.xml") . | nindent 4 }}
```

Inside my PoolServer.xml I have this content:

```
{{- range $index, $val := .Values.ere.adm-users }}
<User Name="{{ tpl "{{ $val.userName }}" $ }} " Password="{{ tpl "{{ $val.password }}" $ }}" />
{{- end }
```

This is what it looks like after i did quite a few changes but it doesn't seem to work.

When i lint it fails with error:

```
[ERROR] templates/: render error in "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml": template: eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml:25:28: executing "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml" at <include (print $.Tem...>: error calling include: template: eric-em-ere/templates/configmap.yaml:14:21: executing "eric-em-ere/templates/configmap.yaml" at <tpl (.Files.Get "fil...>: error calling tpl: Error during tpl function execution for "<User Name=\"{{ .Values.ere.adm-users.userName }}\" Password=\"{{ .Values.ere.adm-users.password }}\" />\r\n": parse error in "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml": template: eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml:1: bad character U+002D '-'
```

Please help me point out what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The [Go text/template documentation](https://godoc.org/text/template) kind of hints at your actual error message: in `.Values.foo.bar` expressions, each of the parts needs to be a valid Go name, which can't include hyphens.  Conventionally value names are camelCased, so you can change both the variable reference and the name of the value to `admUsers` (capital "U", no hyphen).

The multiple layers of `tpl` are confusing and probably unnecessary if your `userName` and `password` will always be simple strings.  You're also not required to assign the iterator of a `range` to anything, and (unlike standard Go) if you assign only one variable it will be the value.

I'd probably write this loop as:

```
{{/* Protect against .Values.ere being missing entirely */}}
{{- $ere := .Values.ere | default dict -}}
{{- range $ere.admUsers }}
<User Name="{{ .userName }}" Password="{{ .password }}" />
{{- end }}
```

If you want it to be possible to put template syntax in the `values.yaml` file for the user names and passwords, you need to construct an appropriate expression for `tpl`; you can't nest the template syntax the way you've shown.

```
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- $ere := .Values.ere | default dict -}}
{{- range $ere.admUsers }}
<User Name="{{ tpl .userName $top }}" Password="{{ tpl .password $top }}" />
{{- end }}
```

If you wanted to construct a string like `{{ .userName }}` and evaluate it you *could*, but putting curly braces in templates gets tricky.  I think the inner body of your loop is equivalent to my first form (it ultimately prints out the `userName` and `password` of each element in the loop).